# ImportError: cannot import name 'arabicocr' from partially initialized module 'ArabicOcr' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, ocr

I am trying to make this code work

```
from ArabicOcr import arabicocr
```

and this error keeps pop to me

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'arabicocr' from partially initialized module 'ArabicOcr' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\aaaa\ExpsLpKeras\Exps\ArabicOcr.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a circular import, you are importing arabicocr from ArabicOcr, but there in ArabicOcr you are importing something from your file.

If your file is ***B***, and *ArabicOcr* is ***A***:

- in ***B*** you have from ***A*** import a
- then in ***A*** you have from ***B*** import b

So importation can not be achieved because both files are dependent one to other.

Comment: Thanx a lot ... i got it!